# Is $y=e^{-x}$ same as $\ln(y)=-x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

I have $y = e^{-x}$

Is it possible to log both sides and get $\ln(y) = -x$.

I suspect this had led me to a mistake in an exam question. Many thanks

Comment: You are correct.  $a=e^b\iff \ln a = b$  (trusting that you are speaking about the usual exponentiation and logarithms of real numbers).

Comment: I've edited the title if you don't like it feel free to change it.

Comment: Notice how you are mapping two values $y$ and $e^{-x}$ to the function $y = \ln(x)$, if $y=e^{-x}$ then since the function for one value of $x$ corresponds with one value of $y$, then in the new function the two values are still equal.

Answer (score 1):

If $A=B $, the only condition you need to log both sides is

$A>0$ or $B>0$.

in your case, 
$B=e^{-x} $ is always $>0$ thus

we get
$$\ln (y)=\ln (e^{-x})=-x $$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes absolutely , you can prove this statement and the proof goes like this

y=e^-x , taking natural logarithm of both sides we get lny=(-x)lne=(-x).

Comment: Please use LaTeX/MathJax to format equations. Here is a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).